# Should I encrypt passwords before sending via Basic Auth?

Tags: php, api, curl, basic-authentication

Very simple question.  For registering and logging in through a RESTful API, should the passwords be encrypted before sending through Basic Authentication; or is Basic Authentication so secure that this would be unnecessary?  This is sent through secure HTTPS.

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imho, if everything is sent via https then everything is already encrypted anyway

Comment: So you say POSTing a password in plain text over HTTPS is fine?  I think others would disagree, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine. The whole interaction is encrypted.

Comment: Should I even bother with HTTP basic authentication then?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using HTTPS it *should* be enough, but you can never be cautious enough so I would at least hash the password with MD5 + a Salt value.

You could use a hidden field to store the Salt value and then generate the hash trough something like `<script>var fullhash=MD5(MD5(*value of the password*)+MD5(*value of the saltfield*));</script>`

you can make any variations of MD5'ing the password and salt value and combining those, md5ing and so on.

Comment: Doesn't a hash become less powerful the more times you encrypt it?  For example, isn't `md5(password+hash)` a stronger encryption than `md5(md5(password)+md5(hash))`?

Comment: You could be right, but if have md5(md5(hello)) wouldn't it take longer to decrypt as you have to decrypt the value of 69a329523ce1ec88bf63061863d9cb14 (which will give you 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592 and then break that one as well?

Comment: I think I read a response once on SO that said since there aren't an infinite number of combinations of md5 results (because it is only a certain string length), that it is easier to crack the md5 of an md5.  However, I also thought your argument would be true so I'm not sure.  I'm by no means a encryption expert, hence the question.

Comment: you were right, I have been talking to my IT Security Professor at University yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for the followup! I've read even more conflicting answers on SO, so the topic continues to confuse me..

Comment: BTW: And even if the other answer here in this post got three upvotes wheras mine is on -1 currently, I would still reccomend to hash the password. Only because the Connection is via HTTPS, it does not mean that the password will not be found out (Man in the middle, etc.) As said before, you can never be cautious enough.